# Циклическая пересылка пакетов в сети

Tags: ip

Привет.
В процессе поиска игрового сервера выяснилось, что мои запросы к айпи 185.21.181.74 попадают в кольцо из двух или трех серверов - 91.213.34.201, 91.213.34.202 и, изредка, неопознанного ***. Судя по всему, это Румыния и не какие-то шаманства на стороне моего провайдера. Куда по таким вопросам стоит писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать [нокам](http://smartwhois.com/whois/91.213.34.202) этой сети:

Comment: ага    whois 91.213.34.202 | grep nocremarks:        NOC: noc@opticnet.roэто если кто не догадался